# How retrieve latitude and longitude via Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How retrieve latitude and longitude via Google Maps API?

Comment: You're going to need to elaborate more on exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 24):

With API v3

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
   alert( 'Lat: ' + event.latLng.lat() + ' and Longitude is: ' + event.latLng.lng() );
});
```

Likewise you can retrieve when a marker is dragged dropped :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function(event) {
   alert( 'Lat: ' + event.latLng.lat() + ' and Longitude is: ' + event.latLng.lng() );
});
```

Comment: Note: since my edit was rejected, this is missing parentheses and a semicolon that need to be added before it will work. Also, suggest changing `dragstart` to `dragend` so that you will get an alert AFTER you place the marker (not as soon as you pick it up).

Answer (score 14):

If you need to find out the latitude and longitude of an address using the Google Maps API, you need to use the [Google Maps Geocoding Service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#Geocoding):

```
var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();

var address = "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain  View";
geocoder.getLatLng(address, function(point) {
         var latitude = point.y;
         var longitude = point.x;  

         // do something with the lat lng
    });
```

If you would like to get the latitude and longitude of a position clicked on your Google map, you can do this in the click event:

```
GEvent.addListener(map, "click", function(marker,point) {
        var latitude = point.y;
        var longitude = point.x;

        // do something with the lat/lng
    });
```

Comment: Thanks!  How do I get GEvent. on my html or jsp page? Do I need to include any js. I am using http://code.google.com/p/struts2-map-plugin/wiki/MapTag, but this does not have tag on map function so looking for something that you showed in second example here.

Comment: @AmolGhotankar   Ghotankar saheb, mi ha code chalawun pahila, nahi chalate mazya ithe, sagalyat pahilya answer cha pan code chalat nahiye, tumhala kahi mahit aasel tar sanga na...mala map war konatyahi point la click kelyawar tya point ch latitude and longitude pahijele.

Answer (score 4):

I have found the result via the following method:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=woking&sensor=false

```
  console.log(response.results[0].geometry.viewport.northeast.lat);
  console.log(response.results[0].geometry.viewport.northeast.lng);
```

Answer (score 1):

like this:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true

more info here
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#Geocoding

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are requesting a way of getting latitude and longitude via code(although you did say API :) ), 
If you are then there are a million posts out there which will show you how(including the ones above), but if you are interested in some kinda utility which just tells you where you are clicking , then Google-maps already comes with it.
check out his post here on how to enable that functionality.

http://varunpant.com/posts/find-longitude-and-latitude-in-google-maps

Answer (score 0):

To add to RedBlueThing's answer you can do stuff like:

```
geocoded_by :address

def address
 [street, city, state, country].compact.join(', ')
end
```

to help you narrow down the exact location, otherwise if you just send in the street the geocoder gem just returns the first instance of that street it finds which could be anywhere in the world

Answer (score 0):

How about ?
Working fine ...

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(....);
var longitude = map.center.lng();
var latitude = map.center.lat();
```

or

```
var longitude = map.getCenter().lng();
var latitude = map.getCenter().lat();
```