# Select location from map by user to get latitude and longitude

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How retrieve latitude and longitude via Google Maps API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770421/how-retrieve-latitude-and-longitude-via-google-maps-api)

I want to add a map to my website with our town as its location. It is used to list shops in the town to our website. The users need to locate their shop location in the map. And we need to get their latitude and longitude positions. Is it possible using google map api ?

Comment: SO is really for concrete questions like "why doesn't this work", not "would this work if I did it"?  You should at least give it a try first, or read google maps'a API before you come around asking.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770421/how-retrieve-latitude-and-longitude-via-google-maps-api#2770439

Comment: The answer is Yes it is possible. A click event (or a marker-move event) on a map can yield latitude/longitude coordinates. But SO is for *specific* coding issues. What is the specific problem you have with your code?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the `head`:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{name:'maps',version:3,other_params:'sensor=false'}]}"></script>
```

And this in a `script` tag:

```
var geo;
function init() {
    var map_elem = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
    var map = new google.maps.Map(map_elem, {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 174.8859710),
        zoom: 2,
        minZoom: 2,
        maxZoom: 4,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    });
    geo = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geo.geocode({
        address: 'New Zealand'
    }, function(e) {
        alert(e[0].geometry.location);
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
```

Adjust as necessary.

See [Geocoding Service - Google Maps JavaScript API v3 - Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding).

Comment: You can also get the variables `viewport` and `bounds` from `geometry`.

Comment: I am very thankful to all to support me. I got a clear idea about how it works. Thanks to all . . .